# I need to know if there is a DMV similar to this one 'sys.dm_pdw_request_steps' in Azure SQL DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

In Azure Synapse Analytics (DWH) I use

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_pdw_exec_sessions
```

to see the last 10,000 logins and `sys.dm_pdw_request_steps` to see the steps of a given request and `sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests` to see current or recent active requests.

However, when I want to do the same in Azure SQL DB I get an error:

> Invalid object name

My question is: are there any similar `sys` views that do the same job in an Azure SQL database?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dmv similar to classic SqlServer: `dm_exec_requests` and `dm_exec_sql_text`

```
SELECT s.text
     , r.session_id
     , user_name(user_id)                   [user]
     , status
     , CAST(GETDATE() - start_time AS TIME) [time]
     , command
     , blocking_session_id                  [blsession]
     , wait_type
     , cpu_time
     , wait_time
     , last_wait_type
     , wait_resource
     , logical_reads
     , reads
     , percent_complete
     , estimated_completion_time
     , start_time
     , plan_handle
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
         CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS s
WHERE r.session_id NOT IN (@@SPID)
```